# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined nodejs

Tags: node.js

Saw a couple threads on this topic but couldn't grasp a solution for my particular use case. In the example below .forEach can't be read. For what reason might this be occurring?

```
const coi = './categories';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(coi, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

```
d:\sw_lbi\index.js:6
  files.forEach(file => {
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at d:\sw_lbi\index.js:6:9
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:163:23)
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log(err, files);` right before the forEach instruction?

Comment: Ahhh I see what's happening. forEach is fine, the file path couldn't be found. I'm trying to use fs.readdir to read json files in the folder "categories". But I believe it can't read the contents in the directory because there is no index.js file contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly because there was an error reported by [readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).  `err` will be set to something.  You should test for it and at least see what it is, maybe begin with a log message.  Perhaps the directory doesn't exist?

```
const coi = './categories';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(coi, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    // deal with it as you see fit
  } else {
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah that's definitely what is happening. Any effective methods of reading folder contents that aren't index.js files?

Comment: Sorry, what?  What do you mean "aren't index.js files"?  Read folder contents the way you are doing so.  If you mean you are trying to skip over any files named `index.js` then just filter the files.  I can demonstrate if you clarify what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, i'll be more clear. I ran into the same error when trying to directly import json files from a folder. When I attempted to use `import` to directly import the json files by folder path, it could only read `index.js` files. So considering this readdir example path is actually correct. I assume it can't read the contents for this same reason.

Comment: The question doesn't mention any of that information. :/  And do you mean `require` (as opposed to `import` which doesn't exist in node.js AFAIK.)  You shouldn't _require_ .json files.  You should read them using fs.ReadFile and then JSON.parse.  Maybe you need to filter so that you ignore non JSON files?  like `files.filter(f => path.extname(f) === '.json')`

Comment: Hahaha okay yeah this issue is definitely prematurely posted. I feel sorry for anyone stumbling across this because it's purpose arose from an ignorant mistake. Might be best to remove the post to not waste others time. Your response was definitely helpful so I thank you for that and I apologise for wasting your time.